# When Jagadguru Ramanandacharya was born?

Tags: rama, ramanand, ramanandi, ramanandacharya, srisampradaya

With historical evidences can you prove when did **Jagadguru Ramanandacharya** was born?

> Kindly give proper references of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Actual Dating of Jagadguru Ramanandacharya:**

There are many myths on the dating of Bhagvan Ramanandacharya many says it's 1299 CE few says it's 1410 CE. So what is the Actual Dating of Bhagvan Ramanandacharya? In this post I will try my best to solve this problem.

According to Narad Pancharatric texts like Vaiśvānara Samhitā and Valmiki Samhita, Bhagvan Ramanandacharya is considered as incarnation of Bhagvan Sri Ram. Agastya Samhitā (not pancharatric) gives details about the life of Bhagvan Ramanandacharya. Sadashiv Samhita also gives information of appearance of Sri Ram as Jagadguru Ramanandacharya.

For clarification: Agastya Samhitā’s are two, one which is related to Narad Pancharatra and another which is independent, in which the shlokas like “वेद-वेद्ये परे पुंसि जाते दशरथात्मजे।”, Janki Stavaraj and life details of Sri Ramanandacharya is found. So don't get confused between these two, eminent scholars like Pandit Saryudas ji has raised these points in his works.

Jagadguru Ramanandacharya has 12 main disciples in which Bhavanandacharya, who, according to Agastya Samhita ch. 132 considers as incarnation of lord Shiva, was initiated by Sri Ramanandacharya and He was non-other than “Sri Vitthal Pant”, written by Sri M in his book “The Journey Continues A Sequel To Apprentice To A Himalayan Master”, Page No. 210.

[image]

And he was the father of Saint Dnyaneshwar, famous commentator of Bhagvad Gita known as Dnyaneshwari Tika. According to Digambar Balkrishna Mokashi in his book “Palkhi: An Indian Pilgrimage”, Saint Dnyaneshwar was born in 1275, Page No. 38.

[image]

If Saint Dnyaneshwar was born in 1275 CE than his father Sri Vitthal Pant would have been born atleast 30–40 years before Saint Dnyaneshwar. So 1235 CE to 1245 CE would be his year of birth.

So, 1299 CE Year Of Birth of Ramanandacharya can't be taken as right as 1235 CE to 1245 CE was Year Of Birth of “Sri Vitthal Pant” who was initiated by Sri Ramanandacharya and 1275 CE is the Year Of Birth of His son Saint Dnyaneshwar than how it is possible that Ramanandacharya would have been born at 1299 CE?

This is also mentioned by Gita Press Gorakhpur Kalyan Magzine Bhagvan Naam Mahima Aur Prarthana Ank, Page No. 310;

[image]

And infact Maharashtrian author Surya Ashoka while mentioning about Saint Dnyaneshwar also mentions this incidence in His work “Amritvani” Page No. 34:

[image]

Surya Ashoka clearly writes that “Sri Vitthal Pant” became the disciple of Sri Raghavanandacharya at Kashi. This again rejects the notion of Sri Ramanandacharya being born at 1299 CE.

❝And infact Sri Malook Peethadhishvar Srimad Rajendra Das Ji Maharaj has also cleared this through his words, He also accepts 1199 CE as the Year of Appearance of Ramanandacharya. As in one of His Bhaktamaal Katha, He raised this point that Sri Vithhal Pant was initiated by Sri Ramanandacharya❞

And infact Malook Peeth (one of the most prominent peeth of Sri Ramananda Sampraday) and other Peetha of Sri Ramananda Sampraday and eminent scholars like Dr. Yogiraj Govats in his work clearly says that year of birth of Bhagvan Ramanandacharya is 1199 CE as that will be absolutely right.

The Year which is popular among scholars and in Sri Ramananda Sampraday for Saint Ravidas birth, who was one of the main 12 disciples of Bhagvan Ramanandacharya is 1267 CE:

According to Datta, Amaresh in Encyclopaedia of Indian Literature Vol 1, Page No 79

[image]

Saint Ravidas was born in 1267 CE than how it is possible that Bhagvan Ramanandacharya would have been appeared in 1299 CE? It clearly marks that the time line of Sri Ramanandacharya would have been much before Saint Ravidas.

Now directly coming to the disappearance year of Bhagvan Ramanandacharya; Although there is no fix year when Sri Jagadguru was disappeared. Let's try to decode it:

Everyone known about famous saint Narsi Mehta but few knows that He was also initiated by Swayam Bhagvan Ramanandacharya at Kashi:

पुरी काशीं समागम्य नरश्रीभर्त्तराट् स्वयम् ।
रामानन्दस्य शिष्योऽभूद्विष्णुधर्म विशारदः ।।

Śrī Narsri (prolapse—Narsi), the supreme Vaishnava devotee, came to Kashipuri and became a disciple of Śrīmad Ramananda.

(Bhavishya Purana, Pratisarga Parva, Vol. 4, Chapter 17, Verse 66)

According to Munshi, Kanaiyalal in Gujarata and its literature Sri Narsi Mehta was born in 1414 CE which is quite close to Ramananda Sampraday’s dating, it dates him around 1425 CE.

Another evidence, according to Bhavishya Puran, Bhagvan Ramanandacharya has given initiation to Sri Guru Nanak Dev Ji as mentioned:

रामानन्दं समागम्य शिष्यो भूत्वा स नानकः ।
स वै म्लेच्छान्वशीकृत्य सूक्ष्ममार्गमदर्शयत् ।।८७।।

Sri Nanak came to Sri Ramananda and became his disciple. He subdued the Mlecchas and showed them the narrow path.

(-Śrīmad Bhavishya Purana, Pratisarga 4.17.87)

And also according to Historians Sri Guru Nanak Dev Ji was the disciple of Jagadguru Bhagvan Ramanandacharya.

And Sri Guru Nanak Dev Ji was born at 15 April 1469 CE as written in History of the Sikhs: The Sikh Gurus, Page No. 50

[image]

Here the year has been written in Vikram Samvat and by minus of 57 years the year will be of CE. So 1526-57 = 1469 CE.

And if 1469 CE is his year of birth than atleast at the age of 20, he would have got initiation from Bhagvan Ramanandacharya.

So, disappearance year is not specified but around 1490 CE to 1495 can be considered as true. As Sri Guru Nanak Dev Ji would have not taken initiation as he born, so atleast if we consider 20 years gap between his appearance and till time he was initiated than the Year 1490 CE to 1495 CE would be absolutely correct.

So, for the time Bhagvan Ramanandacharya was present on earth was around 291 to 296 years.

As Sri Bhaktamaal author Sri Nabhadas ji also writes about the same longevity of Jagadguru Ramanandacharya:

[image]

“बहुत काल वपु धारिकै, प्रणत जनन कौं पार दियो ।” which means for a very long years Bhagvan Ramanandacharya was present on earth and make people to cross this cycle of birth and death.

(-Sri Bhaktamaal Chappay 36)

This kind of longevity is not seen for any Acharya in Bhaktmal, which clearly states that the duration of Bhagwan Ramanandacharya was extremely long. And infact Dr. Ramavatar Sharma of Patna University writes in his book ‘Ishwarvad’ about the appearance year of Ramanandacharya:

[image]

(-Excerpted from Vaishnav Kabir By Dr. Yogiraj Govats, Page No. 47)

1257 Vikram Samvat is equals to 1200 CE which is extremely near 1199 CE.

Although there are 15 more historical evidences I may put here but due to fear of expansion, concluding it here.

Remarks:

1. Jagadguru Ramanandacharya was appeared on 1199 CE which is proven all by historical and Sampradayak evidences.
2. His total time of presence on earth was 291 to 296 years. Such an extreme longevity. And how Ramanandacharya lived so long? Although according to scriptures he was incarnation of swayam Bhagwan Sri Ram but besides that he was great master of Yoga as Swetasvatara Upanishad Ch 2 says “पृथिव्यप्तेजोनिलखे समुत्थिते पञ्चात्मके योगगुणे प्रवृत्ते सति योगाग्निमयं शरीरं प्राप्तस्य तस्य न रोगः न जरा न मृत्युः॥” When the fivefold perception of Yoga, have appeared to the Yogin, then he has become possessed of a body made of the fire of Yoga, and he will not be touched by disease, old age or death. And also written in Hatha Yoga Pradipika खाद्यते नच कालेन वाध्यते नच कर्मणा साध्यते न सके नापि योगी युक्तः समाधिना । means "He who has achieved samadhi by conquering the breath through the great practice of yoga cannot be devoured by Kaal, All his karmic bonds are broken, and he remains untouched by any tantra or mantra; he becomes completely free." And according to Agastya Samhita Chapter 135 Verse 5 Ramanandacharya is denoted by the names योगिवर्यो योगगम्योयोगज्ञोयोगसाधनः । योगसेव्यो योगनिष्ठोयोगात्मायोगरूपधृक् ॥५॥ means “Yogivaryah: The best among all Yogis. Yogagamyah: One who can be known through yoga. Yogajnah: One who knows yoga. Yogasadhanah: Always practicing yoga. Yogisevyah: Worthy of service by yogis. Yoganistah: Steadfast in yoga. Yogatma: The one who knows the essence of yoga. Yogarupadhrik: One who embodies the essence of the goal of yoga.” So, longevity of Bhagvan Ramanandacharya can't be questioned as Great Maharashtrian saint Eknath emphasized a similar concept in Marathi: "प्राण वायुचें धारण तेंचि स्वच्छन्द मत्युचें लक्षण." This means that a yogi who has mastered the control of the life force (prana) through pranayama can have control over their death, essentially being able to live or leave their physical body at will.
3. The case of longevity is quite normal for the one who is practising Yoga as written in ‘Auto biography of a yogi' Published by the philosophical Library. 15 East 40 Streat, New York:
   [image]
4. According to all evidences Jagadguru Ramanandacharya lived for a very long time in front of people his timing will be 1199 CE to 1491–1496 CE which will satisfy the lines of Sri Nabhadas Ji “बहुत काल वपु धारिकै, प्रणत जनन कौं पार दियो”

Thank You For Reading